# Java Client Authenticate to SimpleSAMLPHP

Tags: java, saml

How to integrate SimpleSamlphp to my java application. I did setup simplesamlphp locally and I am able to test it.

But, I am not able to figure out how my java application can use simplesamlphp for running tests

Comment: You need to publish something that shows what you are dont. If not there is no way for us to know why you get a nullpointer

Comment: As per @Stefan, what have you tried? You need a SAML SP stack for the Java side. Refer: [SAML : A SAML stack ](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-stack.html).